# How to stop the virus-like program from corrupting memory

Tags: algorithm, security, process, operating-system

I was asked this question in my recent technical interview. Suppose there is a program that generates random memory addresses and manipulates its contents. What scheme should I employ to prevent this from happening.

My answer was something like having a pre-shared key for our processes and whenever a process is submitted there is a separate process that asks for the PSK. If its correct then an entry for this PID is made in some hash table stored in the memory marking that this is a legitimate process. I dont know how far this is correct and certainly this scheme requires changes for all the processes. How I am going to even achieve this I had no idea. What do you think would be a correct solution.

Comment: How about normal per-process memory allocation.  When the program attempts to write outside its memory, it segfaults.

Comment: Hmm...but isn't it limiting..Like what if I want to get some memory from heap.

Comment: If you can allocate it you can write on it.  There is also per-process limits on the amount of memory the process can allocate.

Comment: Okay...but how are we going to manage which sections of memory address space is for which process...Seems like a bit complicated scheme..Lets see what other guys has to say... :)

Comment: If you want anything more detailed than a few sentences, I think this is too broad. It's very close to asking us how to write an operating system if you want details regarding how to manage the memory layout and allocation.

Comment: I am just curious what someone would have answered given a face to face interview...I am a fresher and he would not be expecting me to write an OS. Just want to see what all different approaches people can come up with :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheme is called [*protected memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) and usually is implemented by the Memory Management Unit inside your CPU, as programmed by the OS.